# Passthrough global keyboard events to a textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way to replay a keyboard event to a textfield and also make the receiving input field add that character to its text? Because I can't make it to work.

Let's say I press `a` on the keyboard and a global handler on body captures it. Now I want to replay it to a given textfield. So if the user presses `a` on the keyboard it would show up inside the textfield, solely based on the event. The event pops up at the input, but the character is not inputted. Is this possible? I want to avoid manipulating the input text with `.val()`;

Example:

```js
$('body').on('keyup', eKeyUp);
$('#mancineni').on('keyup', eKeyUpINPUT);

function eKeyUp(e)
{
 
  $e = $.Event('keyup');
  $e.which = e.which;
  $e.charCode = e.charCode;
  $e.keyCode = e.keyCode;
  $e.shiftKey = e.shiftKey;
  $e.key = e.key;

  $('#mancineni').trigger($e);
    //$('#mancineni').focus();
}


function eKeyUpINPUT(e)
{
    console.log('g', e)
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="mancineni">
```

Comment: Just set the text field's value to `event.key` while handling it at the `body` level.

Comment: I feel like this code will bring you to an infinite loop of events if your input is inside the `body` tag. You should rather append the character to the input field, or, otherwise, set a global boolean which would not trigger the event on the input if `e.target` is already the input :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It feels like you are making this much more difficult than it actually is. Just set the value of the `input` to `event.key` while handling it at the `body` level. Not sure why the need to avoid doing that, perhaps you could explain.

```js
$('body').on('keyup', eKeyUp);
$('#mancineni').on('keyup', eKeyUpINPUT);

function eKeyUp(e){
  $('#mancineni').val(event.key);
}

function eKeyUpINPUT(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="mancineni">
```

Comment: I'm curious/baffled why it is not replayed when the same event actually gets triggered on the input field...

Comment: @AndrásAndrás I don't know what you mean by "replayed". There is only one event which is propagating (bubbling) from its source element up to the `document`. You can intercept (handle) it anywhere along that chain but that shouldn't make the event trigger a second time.

Comment: @AndrásAndrás Perhaps you are stuck on the idea that a `keyup` event and an `input` field have some sort of intrinsic relationship, which they don't. A keyboard event is just as valid on a `div` as it is on an `input`, it's just that an `input` provides a UI to display a keystroke, where a `div` doesn't.

Comment: Yeah, I know this, but I want to know why the character is not appearing in the input when a key{press, down, up}event is simulated.

Comment: @AndrásAndrás Because it didn't organically happen on a form field. Again there is no "simulation" or "replay", there is just an event and if it doesn't originate at a form field, why would you expect a form field to be affected when you handle it at a non-form field?  This is no different than if my fist encounters a "punch" event. If my fist happens to be up against a wall there will be pain. If the punch event is handled by a pillow object, there won't be pain. You are expecting a side-effect of a UI element to somehow dictate what happens on a non-UI element.

Comment: It's like you trigger a click event on a submit button and it "forgets" to submit the form. You see my point?

Comment: @AndrásAndrás Not at all. I think you are confusing the element that the event is triggered on (which may or may not have some kind of native behavior that is specific to that element) with an element that the event propagates to. And, in this case that's not even what's happening. When you press a key down on the document, the event does not propagate to the `input` (although it does work the other way around). Pressing a key down on the document has no relationship to the `input` at all. That's why you must set the `input.value` yourself.

Comment: I've clearly answered your question, if you don't understand it, just say so, do not tiptoe around it. `preventDefault()` stops the ***native*** behavior associated with an event (i.e. clicking a `submit` button causes the `submit` event of a form, clicking a link triggers the navigation to that link's `href`). **There is no native behavior of pressing a key when the document is focused** so there is no native connection between that and any `input` on the page, which is why you'd need to just set the value into the `input` while handling the event at the document level (as I said).